# Go through a table to check if any of its cells contain "T1"

Tags: vba, excel

My code is supposed to go through a table to check if any of its cells contain "T1". The format of all the cells in this table is text.

If it finds a cell with "T1" in it, it will do stuff to cells in other tables. In particular, it assigns `cells(i, 8)` with the value of `cells(i-18, j)`, both of which are in number format, and assign `cells(i,9)` with the value of `cells(k2, j)`, both of which are dates.

When I execute the code, it makes `cells(i,8)` equal to `0` and doesn't do anything to `cells(i,9)`.

Can someone correct this code?

```
Sub TestSub2()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, k2 As Integer

'i ->tier table row counter
'j ->column counter
'k ->"Reading Date" and "PM Executed?" table row counter

'---TIER 1 TABLE---
k = 102
k2 = 84

For i = 21 To 35

    k = k + 1
    k2 = k2 + 1

    For j = 27 To 149
    Select Case Cells(k, j).Value
    Case "T1", "T1, T2", "T2, T1", "T1, T3", "T3, T1", "T1, T2, T3", "T1, T3, T2", "T2, T1, T3", "T2, T3, T1", "T3, T1, T2", "T3, T2, T1"
    Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i - 18, j) And Cells(i, 9) = Cells(k2, j)
    End Select

    Next j

Next i
```

Comment: Without analyzing too much `Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i - 18, j) And Cells(i, 9) = Cells(k2, j)` is a Boolean expression.  It will not assign the desired values to any cells

Comment: Why not use `If InStr(1,Cells(k, j).Value,"T1",vbTextCompare) > 0 Then : Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i - 18, j).Value : Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(k2, j).Value : End If`?

Comment: all i had to do was take out the And ... I keep forgetting about boolean operators -_- , anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially putting the result of a boolean comparison into `Cells(i, 8)`; e.g. *is Cells(i, 8) equal to Cells(i - 18, j) and is Cells(i, 9) equal to Cells(k2, j)*.

```
Select Case Cells(k, j).Value
    Case "T1", "T1, T2", "T2, T1", "T1, T3", "T3, T1", "T1, T2, T3", "T1, T3, T2", "T2, T1, T3", "T2, T3, T1", "T3, T1, T2", "T3, T2, T1"
        Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i - 18, j)
        Cells(i, 9) = Cells(k2, j)
End Select
```

If you feel that you absolutely *must* put both cell value assignments on the same line (you don't for any reason other than cosmetic) then separate with a colon.

```
Select Case Cells(k, j).Value
    Case "T1", "T1, T2", "T2, T1", "T1, T3", "T3, T1", "T1, T2, T3", "T1, T3, T2", "T2, T1, T3", "T2, T3, T1", "T3, T1, T2", "T3, T2, T1"
        Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i - 18, j): Cells(i, 9) = Cells(k2, j)
End Select
```